# Custom Gesture Recognizer doesn't work properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

Both the "touchedBegan" and "touchedEnded" methods get called, but my view only has its background changed on the touchesBegan method but not on the touchedEnded. Here is my code:

```
@implementation ClickableViewGestureRecognizer

NSString* const COLOR_UNTOUCHED = @"#00000000";
NSString* const COLOR_TOUCHED = @"#33000000";

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithTarget:(id)target
                    action:(SEL)action {
    self = [super initWithTarget:target action:action];
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches
       withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    super.view.layer.backgroundColor = [self getTouchedColor];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches
       withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    super.view.layer.backgroundColor = [self getUntouchedColor];
}

- (CGColorRef) getUntouchedColor {
    return [JABColor colorFromHexString:COLOR_UNTOUCHED].CGColor;
}

- (CGColorRef) getTouchedColor {
    return [JABColor colorFromHexString:COLOR_TOUCHED].CGColor;
}

@end
```

Here is colorFromHexString: for anyone who wants to see it as well.

```
+ (UIColor *)colorFromHexString:(NSString *)hexString {
    unsigned rgbValue = 0;
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString];
    [scanner setScanLocation:1]; // bypass '#' character
    [scanner scanHexInt:&rgbValue];
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0 green:((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/255.0 blue:(rgbValue & 0xFF)/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm JABColor is not doing something unexpected by replacing [self getUntouchedColor] with something like [UIColor redColor].CGColor?

Comment: Is there a reason for setting the bg color on a layer? `UIView` has a `backgroundColor` property as well.

Comment: Nope. I actually didn't know that UIView had that.

Comment: Does changing to setting the background color on `UIView` help? If not, can you confirm that `super.view` is not `nil` in both cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the "colorFromHexString" was giving me problems. I threw it away and just used UIColor methods.

Comment: Huh, exactly what I suspected. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have touchesCancelled method ? maybe your Touch events are cancelled and not "ended" , try overriding touchesCancelled too

```
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches
               withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    super.view.layer.backgroundColor = [self getUntouchedColor];
}
```

and can you try just for testing reasons setting [UIColor blackColor] as untouched color ? directly , without converting from hex

Comment: can you log if either cancelled or ended method is called ?

Comment: The ended one gets called only.

Comment: can you try just for testing reasons setting [UIColor blackColor] as untouched color ? directly , without converting from hex